# How to debug obfuscated frontend code using remote source maps

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have a requirement that says unobfuscated code is not allowed to be served to clients in production. Shipping source maps with the code allows the client to see the unobfuscated code, which violates the requirement.

Is there still a way to utilise source maps for debugging purposes while not shipping the source maps to production? So for example, is it possible to host my source maps on my own server, then when I am debugging the site, I can have it retrieve the source maps from my server or something like that?

Comment: Yes, did you try it?

Comment: No, I have not.